# Galería de imágenes Lightbox. Centrar imagen y cambiar de posición el botón cerrar

Tags: css, responsive

Tengo una galería de imágenes con efecto Lightbox, en una página muy larga, con la imagen inicial en la parte de abajo, y al pulsar para que se abra el lightbox en la página nueva, me queda arriba de la página. He conseguido hacer la imagen responsive, y centrarla verticalmente, pero tanto el botón cerrar como el título de la imagen me quedan arriba del todo. Quisiera que quede justo debajo de la imagen (respetando que cada imagen puede tener tamaños diferentes). He probado a cambiar en el CSS algunas propiedades, pero no consigo lo que quiero. ¿Alguna ayuda? Os pego aquí el código CSS:

```
lb-outerContainer {
    width:100% !important;
    max-width:1000px !important;
    height:auto !important;       
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    } 
.lb-outerContainer IMG {
        width:100% !important;
        max-width:1000px !important;
        height:auto !important;
        }
 .lb-dataContainer {
        width:100% !important;
        max-width:1000px !important; 
        }
```

Con este código consigo colocar la imagen en el centro, imagen responsive, pero texto (Imagen1) y cerrar están arriba del todo y yo lo quiero justo encima o debajo de la imagen.

Galería:

```
<div class="container galeria"  >
                    <articles class="row">
                        <article class="col-md-3" style="max-width:500px;">
                            <a href="~/Img/img1.jpg"   id="Enlace1"   data-title="Imagen1" rel="lightbox"  target="_blank" runat="server" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="galeria1" data-type="image" data-lightbox= "example-set-1">                                             
                            <img id="Imagen1" src="~/Img/img1.jpg" alt="Imagen1" runat="server" class="img-thumbnail"  />                             
                            </a> 
                            <p><asp:Label ID="LblImg1" runat="server" Text="Imagen1"></asp:Label></p>                                
                        </article>
                        <article class="col-md-3"  style="max-width:500px;">
                            <a href="~/Img/obras/img2.jpg"  id="Enlace2"  data-title="Imagen2"  rel="lightbox"  target="_blank" runat="server" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="galeria1" data-type="image" data-lightbox= "example-set-1">
                            <img id="Imagen2" src="~/Img/obras/img2.jpg" alt="Imagen2" runat="server" class="img-thumbnail"  />               
                            </a>
                            <p><asp:Label ID="LblImg2" runat="server" Text="Imagen2"></asp:Label></p>                                
                        </article>
                        <article class="col-md-3"  style="max-width:500px;">
                            <a href="~/Img/obras/img5.jpg" id="Enlace3" data-title="Imagen3" rel="lightbox"  target="_blank" runat="server"  data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="galeria1" data-type="image" data-lightbox= "example-set-1">
                            <img id="Imagen3" src="~/Img/obras/img5.jpg" alt="Imagen3" runat="server" class="img-thumbnail"  />               
                            </a>
                            <p><asp:Label ID="LblImg3" runat="server" Text="Imagen3"></asp:Label></p>                                
                        </article>
                        <article class="col-md-3"  style="max-width:500px;">
                            <a href="~/Img/obras/img3.jpg"  id="Enlace4" data-title="Imagen4"  rel="lightbox" target="_blank" runat="server"  data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="galeria1" data-type="image" data-lightbox= "example-set-1">
                            <img id="Imagen4" src="~/Img/obras/img3.jpg" alt="Imagen4" runat="server" class="img-thumbnail" />               
                            </a>
                            <p><asp:Label ID="LblImg4" runat="server" Text="Imagen4"></asp:Label></p>                                
                        </article>
                    </articles>
               </div>
```

Gracias

Comment: Hola, podrías documentar un poco más poniendo un ejemplo? [ask]

Comment: Deberías mostrar un poco el `html` para saber bien como esta estructurada la pagina y poderte ayudar mejor

Comment: Bienvenida a SOes, por favor realiza el [tour] para que conozcas mas sobre el sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Revisa [mcve]

Comment: La página está embebida dentro de una plataforma wordpress. Este es el código de la página embebida:
<iframe id="blockrandom" class="wrapper" src="http://example.aspx" name="iframe" width="100%" height="2800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>